# How can I securely store video tutorials in a React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

How can I securely store video tutorials (around 8GBs) in a React Native app to prevent them from being visible in the gallery or file manager?

I tried using expo-file-system to save the tutorials in either documentDirectory or cacheDirectory, but I'm concerned about the size limit of these directories.

I aim to implement a feature similar to Telegram Messenger, where downloaded media is only accessible within the app. How can I achieve this level of file security and access control in my React Native app?

Comment: Files in the app-internal directory `/data/data/<packagename>/...` are never visible to any file manager or in the gallery on a stock device. On a rooted device those file paths are accessible by a root-file-explorer.